# Strongly typed controller name in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, strong-typing

Is it possible to use strongly typed controller name and action name in asp.net mvc?
for example instead of

ActionLink("ActionName", "ControllerName");

somthing like this

ActionLink(ControllerName(x=>x.ActionName()), ControllerName)

Thanks,
Alexander.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[T4MVC](http://t4mvc.codeplex.com/) does this. Watch this video for an introduction:

http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/jongalloway/Jon-Takes-Five-with-David-Ebbo-on-T4MVC/